# Handling DBNull.Value in company with nullable variable and ternary operator

Tags: c#

I have been struggling with `DBNull.Value` using in company with `ternary operator` for hours, here is the problem:

I declared a null-able DateTime type variable with null as default value, I want to pass `DBNull.Value` if the `acceptanceDate == null` else the value of acceptanceDate is passed:

```
 DateTime? acceptanceDate = null;

if(acceptanceDate != null)
  sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@acceptanceDate ", acceptanceDate ));
else
  sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@acceptanceDate ", DBNull.Value));
```

It works but since there are a lot of similar SQL parameters in my code, I want to use ternary operator (? :) to make it clean and smaller and as you might know both side of return values in ternary operator should be the same type so I have to cast it to object:

```
sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@acceptanceDate ", acceptanceDate == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)acceptanceDate));
```

But I encounter the following error:

***The parameterized query ... expects the parameter '@acceptanceDate', which was not supplied.***

Is there any solution or should I use the `if` clause?

Comment: Can you debug to see what is actually being passed to the function when the error occur?

Comment: try to do this `var acceptance = acceptanceDate == null ? DBNull.Value : (object) acceptanceDate;` and pass acceptance into the sqlparameter.

Comment: How about `sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter("@acceptanceDate ", acceptanceDate ?? (object)DBNull.Value)`?

Comment: Your ternary operator looks fine to me. Try removing that space in the end of `"@acceptanceDate "`.

Comment: @Tyler Roper thanks but I face to an error saying `cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Data.SqlDbType`

Comment: realizing my answer was based on too many assumptions, I've deleted it.

Comment: @Mohammadlm71 That error means you are calling the [wrong overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameter__ctor_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_) of the `SqlParameter` constructor. Then again, you should not be getting `void` type in that expression. It would appear your actual code is different.